# How to write a function to find prime numbers and storing those in an array using swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift

How to write a function to find prime numbers and storing those in an array using swift 4

```
var primeNumber = [Int]()

var numbers = 1...100

for number in numbers {
    if (number % 2 == 0 || number % 3 == 0 || number % 4 == 0 || number % 5 == 0 || number % 6 == 0) || number % 7 == 0 || number % 8 == 0 || number % 9 == 0 {
        print("Its not a prime number")
    } else {
        primeNumber.append(number)
    }
}

print(primeNumber)
```

Comment: What's your issue?

Comment: You using this to practice or need them for a specific project?.. if its not for practice i would suggest not calculating the prime numbers but hardcoding them as its less processing

Comment: You are missing quite some math here. Checking for 4, 6, 8  and 9 is not needed, since they are not prime.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible implementation.  It uses previous primes to check later numbers speeding up the process.  It only checks odd numbers.

```
var primes = [2]

for num in stride(from: 3, through: 100, by: 2) {
    for p in primes {
        if p * p > num {
            primes.append(num)
            break
        }
        if num % p == 0 {
            break
        }
    }
}

print(primes)
```

> ```
> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in stride(from: 2, through: Double(input).squareRoot(), by: 1) {
    if inputSquared % Int(i) == 0 {
        break
    }
    else {
        resultLabel.text = "\(Int(input)) is a prime number!"
    }
}
```

Comment: You should only print ""Input is a prime" if you never hit the else clause. Also, your upper bound should only be square root of input and you can break as soon as you hit the if clause

Comment: Your code is still suboptimal. Instead of `continue` you should have a `break` inside the if clause since as soon as you find the first divider of your input, you know, it can't be a prime. Also, you definitely shouldn't use `through`, but `to`, since `input % input will always be 0, but this doesn't mean the number is a prime. And change `input` to `inputSquared` is just wrong, you should change `input` to `Double(input).squareRoot()`.

Comment: csn you suggeest a comment so I can approve?

Comment: Thanks @DávidPásztor